# ES6 Promisesのpromiseオブジェクトを、他ライブラリの promise風オブジェクトへ変換するには？

Tags: ecmascript-6

**Thenableについて**
・どういう意味？
・then メソッドを持っているオブジェクトがThenable？
・promiseで、.thenと書けばThenable？
・それとも、promiseオブジェクト間の相互変換がThenable？

---

**下記記述で、なぜQ promiseオブジェクトへ変換することが出来るのでしょうか？**
・Qライブラリ専用の書き方？

```
// Q promiseオブジェクトに変換する
Q(promise).then(function(value){
    console.log(value);
})
```

> Q(thenable) とすることでThenableなオブジェクトをQ promiseオブジェクトへと変換することが出来ます

https://github.com/azu/promises-book/blob/master/Ch4_AdvancedPromises/resolve-thenable.adoc#Thenable

---

**「ES6 のPromisesオブジェクト」を、「他ライブラリの Promises風オブジェクト」へ変換する方法について**

・他ライブラリが、promiseオブジェクトを返す関数を公開APIとして用意していれば、それに従うだけ？
・Thenableという考え方が共通しているだけで、相互変換実装方法はライブラリ毎に異なるということでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q Promiseについてはあまり詳しくないので参考程度ですが

> #### Thenableについて
>
> then メソッドを持っているオブジェクトがThenable？

thenを持っているPromiseのようなオブジェクトのことをいいます

> #### 下記記述で、なぜQ promiseオブジェクトへ変換することが出来るのでしょうか？

`Q(promise)`はQ Promiseオブジェクトを返します。引数としてthenableなオブジェクトを与えるとそれをPromiseに変換するのではないでしょうか?

> #### 「ES6 のPromisesオブジェクト」を、「他ライブラリの Promises風オブジェクト」へ変換する方法について
>
> 他ライブラリが、promiseオブジェクトを返す関数を公開APIとして用意していれば、それに従うだけ？  
>     Thenableという考え方が共通しているだけで、相互変換実装方法はライブラリ毎に異なるということでしょうか？

1. ES6 Promiseの場合はその関数は`Promise.resolve`になります。その関数や方法はライブラリによって異なります
2. [Promiseについての注意書き](http://azu.github.io/promises-book/#ch2-promise-resolve)

   > then というメソッドを持っていた場合でも、必ずES6 Promisesとして使えるとは限らない事は知っておくべきでしょう。